# Sum of order of O(1)+O(2)+ .... +O(n)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

What does the sum `O(1)+O(2)+ .... +O(n)` evaluate to?

I have seen its solution somewhere it was written:

```
O(n(n+1) / 2) = O(n^2)
```

but I am not satisfied with it because `O(1) = O(2) = constant`, so according to me it must evaluate to `O(n)` only. I have also seen this in Cormen:

```
Σ(i=1 to n) O(i)
```

In above expression there is only a single anonymous function. This function is not the same as  `O(1) + O(2) + ... + O(n)` which doesn't really have a clean interpretation.

Comment: Probably a question for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math

Comment: it is about math in computer science :)

Comment: If it's [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) as used to calculate [time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), then this question might be better on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more conceptual, and probably a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Time complexity isn't the only thing that can be dealt with using Big O notation.

Comment: This question makes no sense. Big-O expressions O(...) are not values that can be summed in this way.

Answer (score 4):

The question seems to be perfectly on-topic since there is a tag [asymptotic_complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asymptotic-complexity)...

According to [CLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms), p. 49,

*"The number of anonymous functions in an expression is understood to be equal to the number of times the asymptotic notation appears. For example, in the expression*

*sum(O(i), i=1..n)*

*there is only a single anonymous function (a function of i). This expression is thus not the same as O(1) + O(2) + ... + O(n), which doesn't really have a clean interpretation"*

Actually, in your formula, the constants behind the "O" notation may be all different, and their growth may change the asymptotic behaviour of the whole sum. Don't write this!

---

To answer your question more completely, in sum(O(i), i=1..n), you can use the fact that (see [GKP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics) p. 450 for the following)

*O(f(n)g(n)) = f(n) O(g(n))*

Thus, O(i) = i O(1), this time with the same O(1) in your formula. Therefore,

*sum(O(i), i=1..n) = sum(i, i=1, n) O(1)*

*=n(n+1)/2 O(1) = O(n^2)*

This way you can eliminate your sum without trouble.

Comment: "the constants begind the "O" notation may be all different,"; `O(.)` yields a set, not a value. The 'constants' don't exist per se.

Comment: the actual confusion stems from the fact that in expanding the sum, `n ` is no longer treated as a parameter denoting the size of the input but as a cardinal constant. so what you actually have is a countably infinite family of expansions, one for each input size, which does not make for a good tool to describe complexity. however, you can still operate formally on the definitions behind big-Oh notation.

Comment: @Rhymoid. O(n) is a family of functions, but f \in O(n) really means there is a **constant** M such that f(n) <= M g(n). Well, at least it's what all authors say, including the two books I point to in the answer, but also [Knuth TAOCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) and Aho, Hopcroft and Ullman.

Comment: That constant is existentially bound in the definition of the set. The argument of `O(.)` is actually a function, and another function can be in that set. Instead of `O(n)`, one should actually write `O(n :> n)` (`n` maps to `n`), but for convenience, this binding is implicit. Strictly speaking, if you'd write `O(n)` with `n` already bound to a value, you have a subset of `O(1)` (more formally, `O(x :> 1)`). I've seen this explained imprecisely (or even incorrectly) many times, often to the point of confusion of my fellow students. I don't think TAOCP tells it differently, just less precise.

Comment: In summary: there are many interpretations of `O(.)`, some precise, some brief. This question calls for a very precise definition of `O(.)`, one that TAOCP does not give (or you paraphrased it incorrectly). (Also, my interpretation is heavily influenced by functional programming.)

Answer (score 2):

Go by the definition of the Big-Oh notation.

You have `n` functions `f_i`, each of which satisfies

```
a_i * i <= f_i(x) <= b_i * i; x > X_i
```

for some positive constants `a_i, b_i` and sufficiently large `X_i`. let `X = max_i ( X_i )` and sum over the `n` inequalities to get

```
sum_i=1..n ( a_i * i ) <= sum_i=1..n ( f_i(x) ) <= sum_i=1..n ( b_i * i )
```

noting that

```
sum_i=1..n ( min(a_i) * i ) <= sum_i=1..n ( a_i * i )
sum_i=1..n ( b_i * i )      <= sum_i=1..n ( max(b_i) * i )
```

arriving at

```
    min(a_i) * 0.5*(n(n-1))  <= sum_i=1..n ( f_i(x) ) <= max(b_i) * 0.5*(n(n-1))
<=>       A       * (n(n-1)) <= sum_i=1..n ( f_i(x) ) <=        B      *(n(n-1))
```

thus the sum of the functions you started with is indeed `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

sure, O(1) and O(2) is a constant, so we can forget about them. But is O(n/2) constant, I guess no. So try (for your homework) count just second half of the elements:

```
O(n/2) + O(n/2+1) + ... O(n) = ??
```

you will come up with `O(n^2)` :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to find the formula, really not that hard.

You have:
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + .... + n

If you count the list twice (one time ordered from low to high one time from high to low you get twice the result)

((1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + n) + (n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) ...  + 2 + 1)) / 2

This is the same as

((1 + n) + (2 + n - 1) + (3 + n - 2) + ... + (n + 1)) / 2

And this is:

((n + 1) * n) / 2

or as we right in o notion O(n²).